# How to retrieve and echo text from database while keeping format

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP file I am able to retrieve text from my MySQL database, but it isn't in the same format when I echo it.
The image attached shows how the text is in the database, and how I want it to be echoed.

[image: Database text]

But instead, it echoes it without the line breaks.  How can I keep the format?

Comment: You really will have to show us your code if you want help

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the element might also help

Comment: Resolved.  Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<pre>` tag to output pre-formatted text, so it won't be reformatted:

```
echo "<pre>" . $row['content'] . "</pre>";
```

Or use the `nl2br()` function to convert newlines to HTML:

```
echo nl2br($row['content']);
```

Comment: The <pre> tags worked.  Thank you very much!